# Explicitly compute moduli-theoretic map given the parameter for $X_0(2)$

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-functions, moduli-space

Im trying to understand how the modular polynomial is explicitly found. I'm working through the smallest example, $X_0(2)$.

Most sources state the results, but I'am trying to understand exactly how the intermediate steps are done.

I understand how the parameter $j_{2,0}=\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^{24} = \frac{1}{q\cdot\Pi_{n\geq1}(1 + q^n)^{24}}$ is found now, and why its used. My next step is to understand how the $j$-invariants become the rational functions

$$ j(\tau) = \frac{(r + 256)^3}{r^2}$$
and
$$j(2\tau) = \frac{(r + 16)^3}{r}$$  where $r = j_{2,0}(\tau)$ and $j(\tau) = \frac{1}{q} + 744 + 196884q + ...$

The source I am using says " easily verified by comparing the $q$-expansions", I guess my arithmetic is weak and I am having trouble seeing it.

I have been trying to compute the q expansions of the $\eta$ quotient functions and $j$-invariant using sage and see if I can find the patterns. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $r^{2}j$. I think you already know that $r$ is a modular function for $\Gamma_{0}(2)$. Since $j$ is a modular function for $\Gamma(1)=SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma(1)$, $j$ is also a modular function for $\Gamma_{0}(2)$. Thus, $r^{2}j$ is a modular function form $\Gamma_{0}(2)$.

From its infinite product expansion, the Dedekind eta function is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{H}$ with no zeros and no poles on $\mathbb{H}$, hence so is $r$. Moreover, $j$ is also holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$. Thus, $r^{2}j$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$.

Note that $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ has two cusps: $0,\infty$. Each cusp has width 2 and 1, respectively. Because $r$ has no zeros and no poles on $\mathbb{H}$ and has a simple pole at $\infty$, $r$ has a simple zero at $0$. (Remember: $r$ is a meromorphic function on $X_{0}(2)$.) Hence $(r^{2}|_{0}S)(\tau)=r^{2}(S\tau)$ has a Fourier expansion of the form
$$r^{2}(S\tau)=\sum_{n=-2}^{\infty}c_{n}q^{n/2},$$
and therefore $(r^{2}j)(S\tau)$ has a Fourier expansion of the form
$$(r^{2}j)(S\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}q^{n/2}.$$
This means that $r^{2}j$ is holomorphic at the cusp $0$.

Observe that any polynomial in $r$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is a modular function for $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ which is holomorphic except at $\infty$. Since $r^{2}j$ has a Fourier expansion starting with $q^{-3}$, there is a cubic polynomial $x^{3}+\alpha x^{2}+\beta x+\gamma\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ (in fact $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) such that $r^{2}j-r^{3}-\alpha r^{2}-\beta r$ has a Fourier expansion starting with constant term. (Removing the leftmost term from $r^{2}j$ successively, you can get $\alpha=3\times 256, \beta=3\times 256^{2}$. I will omit the detail.) This means that the modular function $r^{2}j-r^{3}-\alpha r^{2}-\beta r$ is holomorphic at $\infty$, hence a holomorphic modular form for $\Gamma_{0}(2)$. By dimension formula (cf. F. Diamond and J. Shurmuan, A First Course in Modular Forms, Chapter 3), $M_{0}(\Gamma_{0}(2))=\mathbb{C}$. Thus, $r^{2}j-r^{3}-\alpha r^{2}-\beta r$ is constant. (In fact, it is the constant term of the Fourier expansion of $r^{2}j-r^{3}-\alpha r^{2}-\beta r$. So, by using Fourier expansion, we can check this constant is $256^{3}$.) Therefore, we get
$$j(\tau)=\frac{(r+256)^{3}}{r^{2}}.$$

If someone finds any error, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of $j$ here ? And I'd like to know how you'd show that  $r$ generates the function field of meromorphic functions on $X_0(2)$,  if possible using Liouville's theorem

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Here $j$ is the same as $j$ in the question, i.e., the Klein $j$-invariant. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I know that is $j$, I mean from what definition do you start here ?

Comment: $j=1728E_{4}^{3}/(E_{4}^{3}-E_{6}^{2})$. I'm not sure that this is the answer you want. And to show that $r$ generates the function field of $X_{0}(2)$, you can use the same argument used to show that $j$ generates the function field of $X(1)$ because the genus $X_{0}(2)$ has genus 0. First, $r$ gives a biholomorhic map of $X_{0}(2)$ onto $P_{1}(\mathb$

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want I deduce those properties of $j$ from the definition? If so, I think you post a new question. And I need to correct one thing: $j$ has a simple pole at 0 since it is in fact a modular function for $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ as you might know.

Comment: As I said, it is unclear what properties of $j$ (and $r$) you assume and use in your answer, and I think what you need is : the modularity, the order at  each cusp, and the 3 first coefficients of the Fourier expansion of $r^2 j$  at one cusp. Altogether you get that $r^{2}j-r^{3}-\alpha r^{2}-\beta r$ is a holomorphic modular form, and hence constant.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed the familarity with the $j$ function. But you feel I need to explain all those things. That's reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: It seems reasonable, since otherwise it is not obvious how it can be generalized, for example to $\Gamma_0(N)$ and other modular functions

Comment: Thank you, my follow up question is where does $r^2j$ come from? I mean, it seems you assume the answer, to show that $(r-256)^3 = r^2j$. Is creating the rational relationships between $j_{0,2}$ and $j$  something that you can massage? Like if we started with some other thing like $r^3j$ (as per your solution).

Comment: First, I should mention I know the modular curve $X_{0}(2)$ has genus 0, so its function field is generated by one element. I also know that $j_{2,0}$ is one of generators. Moreover, I can compute vanishing orders of $j_{2,0}$ at the cusps. Since the modular $j$-invariant is a modular function for $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ (in fact for $\Gamma(1)$), it can be written as a rational function in $j_{2,0}$.

Comment: How to do that? Essentially, my idea is to cancel out the poles of $j$ by multiplying some polynomials in $j_{2,0}$, then the resulting function is holomorphic on $X_{0}(2)$. But it is known that holomorphic modular functions for $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ (in fact $X_{0}(N)$ for any positive integer $N$) are constants. In this way, we express $j$ as a rational function in $j_{2,0}$.

Comment: To cancel out the poles of $j$, we need to know the poles of $j$ and its vanishing orders at the cusps. We know that $j$ has no poles on $\mathbb{H}$. (I guess you also know this.) Since $j$ is a modular function on $\Gamma(1)$, Fourier expansions near 0 and $\infty$ are the same.

Comment: As I said, I can find the vanishing orders of $j_{2,0}$ at the cusps. At the cusp 0, $j_{2,0}$ has a simple pole. But the width of 0 is 2. So we need a polynomial in $j_{2,0}$ with 'at least' double zero at the cusp 0. In this situation, multiplying $j_{2,0}^{2}$ is quite natural. But, as you indicated properly, square is not the canonical power. You can multiply any power of $j_{2,0}$ big enough to cancel out the simple pole of $j$ at the cusp 0. 2 is just the minimal power.

Comment: I have one more remark. Instead of cancelling out the poles, you can cancel out the zeros of $j$. It is known that $j$ has triple zero at $\rho=e^{2\pi i}/3$. By using the theory of complex multiplication, we can see that $j_{2,0}(\rho)$ is an integer (cf. I. Chen and N. Yui, Singular Values of Thompson Series). Keeping this fact in mind, we can find the value of $j_{2,0}$ at $\rho$ using Sage: First, take first few terms of the Fourier expansion of $j_{2,0}$. Second, substitute $\rho$ to it.

Comment: This process will provide us a nice approximation for $j_{2,0}(\rho)$. In this way we can check $j_{2,0}(\rho)=-256$. From this point of view, appearing the third power of some polynomial in $j_{2,0}$ in the denominator is also natrual.

Comment: Thats great, I understand now. Maybe adding your comments to the answer will make the solution more complete! (As in, why its natural to consider $r^2j$) Thanks again!

Comment: @user262841 Hi can you help me in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007201/how-are-dedikind-eta-quotients-connected-to-modular-curves/2007275#2007275 for the intuition behind the generators of $F_N$ the function field of meromorphic functions $X_0(N) \to \mathbb{C}$, in particular how to deduce the degree $[F_N:\mathbb{C}]$ ? tks