# How are Dedikind$\eta$ quotients connected to modular curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, modular-function

Im trying to understand the connection between the Dedekind $\eta$ function and its products/quotients and certain modular curves. Why is that the modular function

$j_2 = \left( \frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)} \right)^{24}$ given as an $\eta$-product generates the function field for the modular curve $\chi_0(2)$. I think the 24 power creates a $1/q$ in the $q$ expansion, (similar to the $j$-invariant, which generates the function field for $\chi(1)$.

I've seen this stated but never with explanation. What is the connection between $\eta$ functions and $\chi_0(l)$ in general?

Thanks!

Comment: and [page 73 of Diamond & Shurman](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Diamond%20and%20Shurman%20-%20A%20first%20cours%20in%20modular%20forms%20-%20page%2073%20-%20j(tau),j(N%20tau)%20generate%20X_0(N).png) it also says that $X_0(N) = \mathbb{C}(j(\tau),j(N\tau))$. I'm not sure what gets more complicated in that case, maybe it is that $j$ isn't bijective on $X_0(N)$ anymore, or because it is because $\Gamma_0(N)$ has many cusps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to prove all the details, but there is what I understand so far :

Let $F$ be the function field of meromorphic functions [$X_0(2) \to \mathbb{C}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#The_Riemann_surface_G.5CH.E2.88.97)

(where $X_0(2)$ is the compactification of $Y_0(2) = \Gamma_0(2) \setminus \mathcal{H}$ a [fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane) for the action of $\Gamma_0(2)$ on the upper-half plane)

- $\eta^{24}(\tau) = e^{2i \pi \tau} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-e^{2i \pi n \tau})$ is a [modular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#Modular_forms_for_more_general_groups) of weight $12$ (you can see it by looking at $\frac{\eta'(\tau)}{\eta(\tau)}$ and expanding $\frac{2i \pi n}{1-e^{-2i \pi n \tau}}$ over its poles),

  so that $j_2(\tau) = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^{24} = e^{-2i \pi  \tau}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+e^{2i \pi n \tau})^{24}}$ is modular of weight $0$ for $\Gamma_0(2)$, i.e. it is meromorphic on $X_0(2)$.
- (looking at $\frac{j_2{}'(\tau)}{j_2(\tau)}$ showing that  $j_2{}'$ doesn't vanish) $j_2(\tau)$ is bijective $X_0(2) \to \mathbb{C}$.
- If $f \in F$ is holomorphic, then it is constant (by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#On_compact_Riemann_surfaces)).
- Take any $f \in F$ and let $a_1,\ldots, a_K$ and $b_1, \ldots , b_M$ be its poles and zeros $\in Y_0(2)$, and look at 
  $$f(\tau) \frac{\prod_{k=1}^K j_2(\tau)-j_2(a_k)}{\prod_{m=1}^M j_2(\tau)-j_2(b_m)}$$
  it has no poles on $Y_0(2)$, and a little work shows that (since it doesn't have any zero on $Y_0(2)$) it doesn't have a pole at the cusp neither, thus it is holomorphic on $X_0(2)$, and it is constant.

  Hence $f \in \mathbb{C}(j_2)$ and $j_2$ generates the function field $F$.

Comment: I'd like if someone could help me improving this answer

Comment: And I essentially adapted the proof that $j$ generates $X_0(1)$ page 73 of Diamond & Shurman

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. In general, $X_{0}(N)$ is a compact Riemann surface. By the theory of compact Riemann surfaces there is a plane projective curve, say $C_{N}$, which is isomorphic (in the complex analytic sense) to $X_{0}(N)$. So the problem determining the function field of $X_{0}(N)$ is reduced to that determining the function field of $C_{N}$.

Comment: On the other hand, the curve $C_{N}$ is the zero locus of a polynomial $\Phi(X,Y)$ given by the relation between $j(\tau)$ and $j(N\tau)$. The affine coordinate ring of $C_{N}$ is $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/\langle\Phi(X,Y)\rangle$, and its field of fractions is the function field of $C_{N}$. This is isomorphic to the function field of $X_{0}(N)$. But since $\Phi(X,Y)$ is defined by the equation $\Phi(j(\tau),j(N\tau))=0$, the map $j\mapsto X$, $j(N\tau)\mapsto Y$ gives a surjective homomorphism the function field of $X_{0}(N)$

Comment: onto the function field of $C_{N}$. Since homomorphisms between fields are injective, it is in fact an isomorphism. Hence the function field of $X_{0}(N)$ is generated by $j(\tau)$ and $j(N\tau)$. Moreover, it is know that the polynomial $\Phi(j(\tau),Y)\in\mathbb{C}(j)[Y]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $[SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_{0}(N)]$. Thus the extension degree of the function field of $X_{0}(N)$ over $\mathbb{C}(j)$ is $[SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_{0}(N)]$.

Comment: But if you just want to find generators, you can prove that every modular function for $\Gamma_{0}(N)$ is a rational function of $j(\tau)$ and $j(N\tau)$ by the use of complex analysis. You can find a complex analytic proof of this fact and properties of $\Phi(X,Y)$ in the book `Primes of the form $x^{2}+ny^{2}$' written by D. Cox.

Comment: In sum, the function field of $X_{0}(N)$ is generated by at most two functions because it is isomorphic to the function field of a plane curve. But since this curve is defined by the relation between $j(\tau)$ and $j(N\tau)$, they are two generators of the function field of $X_{0}(N)$. But your answer shows that the function field of $X_{0}(2)$ is generated by $j_{2}$. It remains to explain this.

Comment: According to the genus formula for $X_{0}(N)$ (please see, for example, p. 68 of Diamond and Shurman), the modular curve $X_{0}(2)$ has genus 0, so it is complex analytic to $P^{1}\mathbb{C}$, hence we can expect that there exists a function generating the function field. As you showed, $j_{2}$ is such a function. The point is that the existence of a function like $j_{2}$ and the validity of the argument given above depend on the genus 0 property of $X_{0}(2)$.

Comment: This suggests that we can expect the existence of a function like $j_{2}$ only for the modular curves $X_{0}(N)$ of genus 0. I hope that this comment is helpful althought my explanation is too naive.